# Keeping consumer alive using Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm looking for a "low-cost" method to keep a consumer alive when I'm not actively polling. I.e., still processing records from the last poll, and I don't want the consumer connection to time out.

Some functions that look promising:

- [wakeup](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#wakeup())
- [commitAsync](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitAsync(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetCommitCallback))

In each case this would be non-standard usage of the API, so I'm not sure it would be a reasonable / rational approach.

RE: Setting the connection timeout higher - I *want* the consumer to timeout if it gets wedged. My question pertains to one section where I've fetched a block of records and separate threads are working through them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) seems to suggest you should call `pause()` and then keep actively polling. If you call `poll()` while paused, nothing will be returned.

> For use cases where message processing time varies unpredictably,
>   neither of these options may be sufficient. The recommended way to
>   handle these cases is to move message processing to another thread,
>   which allows the consumer to continue calling poll while the processor
>   is still working. Some care must be taken to ensure that committed
>   offsets do not get ahead of the actual position. Typically, you must
>   disable automatic commits and manually commit processed offsets for
>   records only after the thread has finished handling them (depending on
>   the delivery semantics you need). Note also that you will need to
>   pause the partition so that no new records are received from poll
>   until after thread has finished handling those previously returned.

The documentation for `pause()` confirms this:

> Suspend fetching from the requested partitions. Future calls to
>   poll(long) will not return any records from these partitions until
>   they have been resumed using resume(Collection). Note that this method
>   does not affect partition subscription. In particular, it does not
>   cause a group rebalance when automatic assignment is used.

Comment: So continuing to **poll** when the consumer is **paused** - this is a 'keep-alive'?

Comment: That's what I understand from the documentation. I'd say it's at least worth a shot.

Answer (score 4):

Since Kafka 0.10.1, the consumer no longer heartbeats during `poll` calls. It runs the hearbeat in a separate thread. So if that's your version, there is nothing else to do. See [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread)